# How to get processes that belongs to a particular session?

Tags: c#, asp.net, session, process

I want to get all the processes that is meant for a particular session.
i.e if there are two persons who are using my web application then i want to get all the processes used by user1 and all the processes used by user2.

```
I can get all processes by writing Process.GetProcesses() but how to get it in a group.
e.g:

User1:  Process342
User1:  Process151
User2:  Process452
User2:  Process674
User2:  Process111
```

Can anyone please help.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how ASP.NET & IIS works together - these articles may help:

1. http://www.code-magazine.com/Article.aspx?quickid=0511061
2. http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/iis/ASPNETInternalsIISAndTheProcessModel.aspx
3. http://msdn.microsoft.com/hi-in/magazine/cc188942(en-us).aspx

Now coming to your specific question, ASP.NET runtime gets hosted in IIS worker process. Session is just a logical scope to identify user session from browser and ASP.NET provides a state bag to store session specific values. All users (sessions) get served by same (set of) worker process(es) - so finding processes per session does not make any sense. All you can do is to find out processes executing on the web server.

Answer (score 0):

I see two simple ways to do what you want in C# (don't know about ASP.NET):

You could filter the Processes by SessionId to get the processes running for a single session

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().Where(p => p.SessionId == sessionID).ToArray();
```

Or you could sort the results to group them by session

```
Process[] processes = Process.GetProcesses().OrderByDescending(p => p.SessionId);
```